# Azure storage local development

Tags: development-process, linux, azure, osx

I want to try a whole bunch of azure services in my project. Now I facing a design problem for the development cycle. I want to test everything local and only it works I want to push it do azure. My OS is manly linux and osx, but there is e.g. no azure storage emulator? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use interfaced services instead of the raw sdk. Then you can mock them for testing